# Issue in running storybook for vuejs and preact together in one project

Tags: vue.js, storybook, preact

I am trying to merge 2 ui components library together for vuejs and preact but getting some issues in storybook. I have successfully run build for both with same script. Now when I tried to create 2 scripts for storybooks of both framework then getting below errors.

**When running script `yarn storybook:react` getting below error-**

```
    ERR! TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
    ERR!     at validateString (internal/validators.js:120:11)
    ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:3)
    ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    ERR!     at interopRequireDefault (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:178:16)
    ERR!     at getContent (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:194:10)
    ERR!     at loadPreset (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:203:20)
    ERR!     at /projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:256:18
    ERR!     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    ERR!     at loadPresets (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:255:18)
    ERR!     at loadPreset (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:225:81)
    ERR!  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
    ERR!     at validateString (internal/validators.js:120:11)
    ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:3)
    ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    ERR!     at interopRequireDefault (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:178:16)
    ERR!     at getContent (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:194:10)
    ERR!     at loadPreset (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:203:20)
    ERR!     at /projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:256:18
    ERR!     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    ERR!     at loadPresets (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:255:18)
    ERR!     at loadPreset (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:225:81) {
    ERR!   code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
    ERR! }
```

**When running script `yarn storybook:vue` getting below error -**

```
    ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined
    ERR!     at Object.webpackFinal (/projects/dwc/.vueStorybook/main.js:19:21)
    ERR!     at /projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:294:28
    ERR!     at async Object.webpack (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/cjs/presets/custom-webpack-preset.js:42:28)
    ERR!     at async starterGeneratorFn (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/cjs/index.js:116:16)
    ERR!     at async Object.start (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/cjs/index.js:272:14)
    ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
    ERR!     at async storybookDevServer (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/dev-server.js:207:28)
    ERR!     at async buildDevStandalone (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:120:31)
    ERR!     at async buildDev (/projects/dwc/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:174:5)
```

**My configurations are below- **

Node Version - `12.22.0`

**Rollup file -**

```
    import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
    import multiInput from 'rollup-plugin-multi-input';
    import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
    import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
    import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
    import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
    import path from 'path';
    import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
    import vue from "rollup-plugin-vue";
    import tsPaths from "rollup-plugin-tsconfig-paths"
    
    const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'];
    
    const reactConfig = {
      input: [
        'src/react/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
        '!**/*/style/**',
        '!**/*.stories.tsx',
        '!src/react/*.d.ts',
        '!src/react/assets/**',
        '!**/*.test.js',
      ],
    
      plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal(),
        resolve({ extensions, browser: true }),
    
        babel({
          extensions,
          include: [
            'src/react/**/*',
            '!**/*.stories.tsx',
            '!**/style/**',
            '!src/react/*.d.ts',
            '!src/react/assets/**',
            '!**/*.test.js',
          ],
          exclude: ['node_modules/**', 'src/vue'], // only transpile our source code
        }),
    
        postcss(),
        multiInput({ relative: 'src/react' }),
        tsPaths({ tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.react.json' }),
      ],
    
      output: [
        {
          dir: 'dist/react/cjs',
          format: 'cjs',
          sourcemap: true,
        },
        {
          dir: 'dist/react/esm',
          format: 'esm',
          sourcemap: true,
        },
      ],
    }
    
    const vueConfig = {
      input: "src/vue/index.ts",
      output: [
        {
          format: "cjs",
          file: "dist/vue/index.js",
          sourcemap: true
        },
        {
          format: "esm",
          file: "dist/vue/index.esm.js",
          sourcemap: true
        }
      ],
      plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal(),
        resolve(),
        vue(),
        commonjs(),
        postcss(),
        tsPaths({ tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.vue.json' }),
      ]
    }
    
    export default [reactConfig, vueConfig];
```

**Package.json file -**

```
    {
      "main": "dist/vue/index.js",
      "module": "dist/react/cjs/index.js",
      "files": [
        "dist"
      ],
      "scripts": {
        "clean": "rimraf dist",
        "build:types": "tsc --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir dist/esm && tsc --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir dist/cjs",
        "build:js": "rollup -c",
        "build:css": "node-sass -r src/react -o dist/react/esm && node-sass -r src/react -o dist/react/cjs",
        "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:js && npm run build:css",
        "storybook:react": "start-storybook -p 6006 -c .reactStorybook",
        "storybook:vue": "start-storybook -p 6007 -c .vueStorybook",
        "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "classnames": "*",
        "preact": "*",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "7.8.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.9.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-alias": "^3.1.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^14.0.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^9.0.0",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.13",
        "@storybook/vue3": "^6.5.9",
        "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.28.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "2.28.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.33",
        "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
        "eslint": "6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.1.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "7.2.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "6.10.1",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "5.2.1",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "2.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "2.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.12",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
        "preact": "^10.4.1",
        "prettier": "2.0.4",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "rollup": "^2.70.2",
        "rollup-plugin-babel": "4.4.0",
        "rollup-plugin-multi-input": "1.1.1",
        "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
        "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^3.1.1",
        "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.31.2",
        "rollup-plugin-vue": "^6.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "typescript": "^4.6.3",
        "vue": "^3.2.33",
        "vue-class-component": "^7.2.6",
        "vue-loader": "^16.8.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.17.12",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.17.12",
        "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/preact": "^6.5.9",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "rollup-plugin-tsconfig-paths": "^1.1.8"
      }
    }
```

**My `main.js` file configurations are-**

**`.reactStorybook/main.js` -**

```
    const path = require('path');
    const prettierConfig = require('../.prettierrc.js');
    
    module.exports = {
      stories: ['../src/react/**/*.stories.tsx', '../src/react/**/*.stories.jsx'],
      addons: [
        '@storybook/addon-actions',
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-knobs/register',
        {
          name: '@storybook/addon-storysource',
          options: {
            rule: {
              // test: [/\.stories\.jsx?$/], This is default
              include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/react')], // You can specify directories
            },
            loaderOptions: {
              prettierConfig,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      webpackFinal: async (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
              }
            },
          ],
        });
    
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.stories\.tsx?$/,
          loaders: [
            {
              // adds source decorator into stories
              loader: require.resolve('@storybook/source-loader'),
              options: { parser: 'typescript' },
            },
          ],
          enforce: 'pre',
        });
    
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        });
    
        config.resolve.alias = {
          '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/react'),
          '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/react/Components/'),
          '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/react/utils/'),
          '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/react/Pages/'),
          '@constants': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/react/Constants/'),
        };
    
        config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
    
        return config;
      },
      framework: "@storybook/preact",
      core: {
        builder: "webpack5"
      }
    };
```

**`.vueStorybook/main.js`**

```
    module.exports = {
        stories: ['../src/vue/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
        addons: [
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-essentials',
        '@storybook/addon-interactions',
        ],
        webpackFinal: async (config) => {
            config.module.rules.push({
              test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', { loose: true }],
                    plugins: [
                        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }]
                        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object', { loose: true }]
                        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }]
                    ]
                  }
                },
              ],
            });
            config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
        
            return config;
        },
        framework: "@storybook/vue3",
        core: {
            builder: "webpack5"
        }
    };
```